# what's the fastest way to reset a julia array to all zeros?

Tags: arrays, memory, julia

suppose I have an existing array like

```
x = rand(4)
```

and then I want to reset `x` to zero. Can I avoid doing `x = zeros(4)`. I'm concerened about memory allocation.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The best way to do it in one line is:

```
x .= zero(y)
```

or

```
fill!(x, zero(y))
```

where `y` is the type of number you want it to be like. The reason why this way is good is that it works in all cases. If `x` is any type, using this will work as long as `y` matches the type (indeed, you can use `y = x[1]`).

When I mean any type, I mean that this also works for odd number types like [SIUnits](https://github.com/Keno/SIUnits.jl). If you use this command, a package could support SIUnits without ever having to import the package since this will apply the correct units to the `x` values (as long as all of its operations are correct in units), while `fill!(x, 0.0)` will error due to wrong units (you can also use `fill!(x, zeros(y))`. Otherwise, you'd have to check for units and all sorts of things.

Comment: Actually `fill!(x, 0.0)` does the automatic conversion and just works apparently. In any case, `fill!(x, zero(eltype(x)))` would be more coherent, since the result must have the same type as the element type of `x`, as it is being placed back in the same array.

Comment: `fill!(x, 0)` relies on being able to convert 0 to the proper type. In some cases, that can't be done. For example, you can't convert 0 (dimensionless) to `0meters`.  Another would be a vector of `RGB` values, where converting a scalar to an RGB value is ill-defined.

Comment: In Julia 0.5 you can also do `x .= 0`.  Note that all three of these methods actually call `fill!` under the hood.

Answer (score 3):

You can do

```
fill!(x, 0.0)
```

This overwrites the contents with zeros.

This should be just as efficient as just doing a `for` loop, though:

```
for i in 1:length(x)
    x[i] = 0.0
end
```

Indeed, if you do `@edit fill!(x, 0.0)`, you will see that this is basically what it is doing (except that it uses `@inbounds` for more efficiency).

Answer (score 2):

It seems to me people have suggested nice alternative ways of doing this but no-one addressed the actual question of "what's the most efficient way (specifically in terms of memory)".

So here it is. Given:

```
f1(x) = x    = zeros(size(x));
f2(x) = x[:] = zero(x[1]);
f3(x) = fill!(x, zero(x[1]));
f4(x) = x    = zero(x);
```

We have:

```
julia> x=rand(1000,1000); @time (for i in 1_000_000_000; x=f1(x); end;)
  0.000715 seconds (3 allocations: 7.629 MB)
```

```
julia> x=rand(1000,1000); @time (for i in 1_000_000_000; f2(x); end;)
  0.000691 seconds (2 allocations: 32 bytes)
```

```
julia> x=rand(1000,1000); @time (for i in 1_000_000_000; f3(x); end;)
  0.000702 seconds (2 allocations: 32 bytes)
```

```
julia> x=rand(1000,1000); @time (for i in 1_000_000_000; x=f4(x); end;)
  0.000704 seconds (2 allocations: 7.629 MB)
```

---

PS. As a response to some comments below, the comparison of the above methods is purely intended to demonstrate the difference in approaches *quantitatively* rather than in generic abstract terms, so as to more fully address the question of "what's more efficient, by how much" etc.
It is not intended to imply that `f1` or `f4` are *mutating* functions; they are not, they return a reference to a new object in memory; i.e. they are there for completeness to demonstrate the *bad* alternatives that OP is presumably trying to avoid.

I just felt that a question about "efficiency" deserved some numbers to complement the suggestions offered by my colleagues :)

Comment: `f1` and `f4` don't do what you want them to do.

Comment: Both `x[:]` and `!` are syntax (well, `!` is convention) for in-place, so they won't have any temporaries. So it's not surprising they are the same. `x    = zero(x)` and `x = zeros(length(x))` are vector functions which return vectors, and thus it's not surprising they allocate. I don't know what else you're trying to show here.

Comment: @Matt: I was aware of f1 (I edited it now to be consistent), but why f4? Care to elaborate?

Comment: @ChrisRackauckas I wasn't implying it would be surprising. It's just a comparison. OP was worried about memory allocations, I put both cases of assigned and in-place operations to show some numbers. As for `x[:]` and `fill!` not being surprising they don't have any temporaries and therefore being the same, well, that's true, but it's also not guaranteed. We could talk theory all we want but a benchmark removes all doubt, no? :)

Comment: Neither `f1` nor `f4` will modify the function's argument.  They both create a brand new array, and they happen to name it the same thing as the function argument.  But that just changes what the name `x` points to within the local scope of the function; it doesn't have any effect on the array that the function was called with.

Comment: @MattB. ah I see; yes of course, that was exactly the intention here. OP never explicitly said "I want an in-place alternative", he/she just said "I'm worried about allocations", so I explored all options by way of comparison to show the difference between the difference approaches (i.e. mutation vs new reference). But thanks for pointing it out regardless; I did not intend it to seem like I was suggesting those were non-memory-allocating options, so it's always good to clarify! :)